# Where to place Mobile detect code?

Tags: magento-1.7, php, magento-1

I saw this method as efective to detect if the user is using a mobile device:

```
$isMobile = Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match(
    Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
    $_SERVER
);
```

But I was wondering where would be best to add this?

Comment: Did my solution helped/worked for you ?

Comment: The code was in php and I needed to find it in html actually but for the asnwer I posted it would been appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code in a file which will available to all pages like

- Header (app/design/frontend/{package }/{theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml)
- Footer (app/design/frontend/{package }/{theme}/template/page/html/footer.phtml )

So you will be able to check `$isMobile` on all pages.